# Make Install Linux Kernel Location Change

Tags: linux, compiling, linux-kernel

I have already run `make` to compile the Linux Kernel 3.12.6, but when I run `make install`, I don't want it to install it in `/boot` (as I don't want another OS on the hard disk). How can I change it so it installs somewhere else?

My intentions are to create an `iso image` (not to install Linux on my hard disk for boot) to test in an emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run `make install`, the kernel and modules are already compiled.

The compiled kernel is in the source directory at "arch/x86/boot/bzImage" (or similar depending on your compression), note the relative path here.

normally you can manually "install" it with `sudo cp arch/x86/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-version` and updating grub.

Comment: So, now I would create a new directory (somewhere else) where I will have the `bzImage` and a `grub.cfg` file and run `grub-mkrescue -o` with the directory (and the .iso name) to create a bootable iso. (I used `grub-mkrescue` command when programming my own OS, but don't know how Linux needs it)

Comment: Well, making a bootable iso takes a bit of knowledge and work. If you get stuck, best to ask a new question.